# Performance Issues Saving ActiveMQTextMessages

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am trying to consume ActiveMQTextMessages (received as Message objects) and store into a file given a very high data rate (9K a second is the target). I am running into performance problems trying to save the messages into a set of files.

I am currently receiving at 30K a second and pushing into a ConcurrentLinkedQueue of which I have a configurable set of workers popping off the queue until they reach a max internal queue amount.  This all seems fine. The issue I am having is when I am passing the concatenated text (longest running time I think) to the compression algorithm. I would be willing to store the textmessage received from the message but, when I stored it out, what would be a more efficient way to handle the following pseudo?

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(op);
Deflater df = new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_SPEED);
DeflaterOutputStream out = new DeflaterOutputStream(fout, df);
while(!localQueue.isEmpty())
{
    Message msg = localQueue.remove();
    ActiveMQTextMessage amqtextmesssage = (ActiveMQTextMessage)msg;
    String textMessage = amqtextmesssage.getText();
    String jmsCorrID = amqtextmesssage.getJMSCorrelationID();
    Destination destinationID = amqtextmesssage.getJMSDestination();
    long jmsTimeStamp = amqtextmesssage.getJMSTimestamp();

   //FORMAT FOR SPECIFIC OUTPUT TO BE POSTPROCESSED
   String result = String.format(/*format strings here*/);
   InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes());
   
   int i;
    while ((i = is.read()) != -1) {
        out.write((byte) i);
        out.flush();
    }
    is.close();
}
```

Comment: This sentence seems to be incomplete `The issue I am having is when I am passing the text information to javas Deflate`. What is the issue you're having? What are the symptoms?

Comment: Do you keep the outputstream open all the time you write?

Comment: @Ivan I am backing up on my queues and my CPU utilization is skyrocketing. My assumption is that getting the text, formatting, and then passing to the compression algorithm is causing me delay. Is there a way to get the the byte string from Message or AMQTextMessage without going to text? I would be willing to store the entire message and all payload information. I am batching between 200-500 messages each message is approximately 700 lines. That batch cycle takes between 30-45 seconds to write with 25 threads performing similar actions.

Comment: @HRgiger I close it once the localQueue is empty.

Comment: You can have a look at `getContent()` method. I recommend you to use a profiler to collect more information to base your hypothesis before trying implementation strategies

Comment: @ivan do you have a good suggestion on a profiler?

Comment: I've used JProfiler for quite a while. JVisualVM is most probably already installed on your dev machine and also has some helpful capabilities - it's included with JDK. There are other options on the internet